# Capturing the error stream from a sed command

Tags: sed, redirect

How do I capture any error from a `sed` command into a file? Here is the `sed` command I am using:

```
    sed -e 's/'old_word'/'new_word'/' temp_file > output_file
```

Now, when everything goes well, modified contents from `temp_file` are captured in `output_file`. But let's say that `output_file` happens to be read only. In this case, instead of error being shown on screen , I would like it to be redirected to `error_file`. How can I do that? I tried adding `2> error_file` to the end of the above command but that did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: In what way did it "not work"? What are all the extra quotes for? You can do: `sed -e 's/old_word/new_word/' temp_file > output_file 2> error_file`

Comment: It did not work because I made output_file read only and executed the command. The error message still showed up on the console. The extra quotes are because old_word and new_word are actually variables in my script.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/'old_word'/'new_word'/' temp_file > output_file 2>error_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Following command works for me like charm:

```
sed -e 's/'old_word'/'new_word'/' temp_file > output_file 2> sed_error
```

Just make sure you didn't put space between `2` and `>`.